# Simulating Manet using ns2

Tags: ns2

I'm simulating MANETs, I need the node to be able to broadcast periodic messages and unicast service messages at the same time. Could you please help me learn how to do that. 
Also, I would like to have an eavesdropper (Man in the middle) that can intercept both the broadcasted and the unicasted messages. I would appreciate it if you help me connect this node correctly in between.
Best regards.

Comment: Please start with the Manet simulation examples, manet-examples-5.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pKk3Q3gdSej6u2xQLKUZemLsDrpWHfxn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually no longer have the problem related to how to send the messages. Currently, I want to be able to receive both kinds of messages at the eavesdropper level, I tried doing so but, I need to have an eavesdropper connected to a node. which means that if I have 10 nodes then I need 10 eavesdroppers. I want to have 1 eavesdropper that covers a specific region with its mobile nodes. Could you please help me receive the messages at a lower layer from nodes I'm not connected to.